# Parsing JSON file in Scala

Tags: json, scala, parsing, lift-json

I've got a JSOn File:

```
JsonString="""{"schema":{"type":"struct","name":"emp_table","fields":[{"field":"emp_id","type":"string"},{"field":"emp_name","type":"String"},{"field":"city","type":"string"},{"field":"emp_sal","type":"string"},{"field":"manager_name","type":"string"},]},"payload":{"emp_id":"1","emp_name":"abc","city":"NY","emp_sal":"100000","manager_name":"xyz"}}"""
```

I want to parse it and get the values into an `Array(1,abc,NY,100000,xyz)`

I used Lift Json API in Scala:

```
case class Emp(val emp_id: String, val emp_name: String, val city: String, val emp_sal: String, val manager_name: String)

val stocks = ArrayBuffer[Emp]()
val json = JsonParser.parse(EmpString)

val elements = (json \\ "payload").children
for ( acct <- elements ) {
val stock = acct.extract[Emp]
stocks += stock
}
stocks.toArray
}
```

but its giving me as

```
Array[Emp] = Array(Emp(1,abc,NY,100000,xyz))
```

Can anyone guide me to parse this Json file maybe using any other API like GSON or jackson?

Comment: Could you clarify what your problem is exactly? From what you've explained, it looks like the JSON object is parsed correctly, given that your code explicitly ignores the schema and only takes the `payload` object. You can construct an array of the object fields manually afterwards, like `Array(stock.emp_id, stock.emp_name, stock.city, stock.emp_sal, stock.manager_name)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got an `Array[Emp]`, and you want `Array[String]`, you can always just `flatMap()` it.

```
empArr.flatMap(_.productIterator).map(_.toString)
//res0: Array[String] = Array(1, abc, NY, 100000, xyz)
```